# How can I use node-gyp to run C++ code with node.js

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp

[Node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/) is a cross-platform command-line tool written in Node.js for compiling native addon modules for Node.js. I am trying to get my node program to run some C++ I've written. Node-gyp seems to make this process easier as in this [example](https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/master/test/addons/hello-world), which I was able to run by doing `node-gyp configure` followed by `node-gyp build` and then running with `node test.js`

I'm still having trouble understanding how to set up the `binding.cc` and `binding.gyp` files. Does anyone know whats going on or know of any good guides/documentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Addons documentation page](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) and [node-addon-examples](https://github.com/rvagg/node-addon-examples) linked from that page should be a good start.  Also watch [this slides](http://kkaefer.github.io/node-cpp-modules/) on basics of binary modules (it uses older node-waf as a build tool though)